# Why does Play Framework war contains duplicate class files?

Tags: java, playframework, tomcat7, playframework-1.x

Following the tutorial on Play I have managed to get the project to build after recreating and porting the code over to it.

So what I am doing now is running the following commands to try and create the war.

- List item
- play clean c:\myproject
- play dependencies c:\myproject
- play precompile c:\myproject
- play war c:\myproject -o c:\myproject_war\myproject.war

I am seeing the .class files in 2 locations and this makes no sense to me. Additionally, why are the .java files being packaged as well? 
The locations where the class files are being stored are

- myproject.war\WEB-INF\application\eclipse\classes\controllers...
- myproject.war\WEB-INF\application\precompiled\java\controllers...

Also, I did change the application.conf file to set the application.mode=prod because it was set to dev.

Is this how it is suppose to be where we have duplicate class files as well as source code being deployed in the war and if so which class files are actually being used by the system?

This app runs on Tomcat 7.

Comment: Update: This command will help not to deploy most of the source java files.

C:\local\Projects\JHS\war>play war C:\local\Projects\JHS --exclude app\controllers:app\models:app\utils:app\jobs:app\helpers:app\notifiers -o jhs.war

Comment: Useful information update: In DEV mode, Play compiles your Java source when it receives the first incoming HTTP request.  It then monitors your source files on disk, and will attempt to recompile and restart the application lifecycle if there's a change.

In PROD mode, Play compiles all the source to .class files once right away, and uses those.

You can also "precompile" your app, and and then pass in "-Dprecompiled=true" as a JVM argument at startup to let it know that the .class files already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information that I have obtained from another forum it just seems that it is what Play does and unless I want to go down the path of writing my own python code to clean up what Play does there is not much I can do about this.

[Google Groups - Play Framework ([1.2.4] Does Play work off of .Java files or the compiled .class files?)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/9P8QdD-hzNs)